# VSCode extension TreeView set selected

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a `TreeDataProvider` and populated it with `TreeItem s`. I would like to be able to set the `TreeItem` that is selected based on the current editor window, like happens in the Explorer/Open Editors view.

I have looked through the API but cannot find any way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `reveal()` API that was [added in VSCode 1.21.0 (February 2018)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_21#_custom-views-reveal) for this.

This requires you to first obtain a `TreeView` instance using `createTreeView()`:

```ts
const treeView = vscode.window.createTreeView("viewId", {treeDataProvider: provider});
treeView.reveal(item, {select: true});
```