# How can I programatically select a tree item in a VS Code tree view given its label?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I followed the example provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534723/simple-example-to-implement-vs-code-treedataprovider-with-json-data) to create a basic **VS Code tree view**.
I am now looking for **how to to select** (or unselect) **an item in a tree view given its label**.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any (simple) example.

Comment: Will [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47775269/vscode-extension-treeview-set-selected) help? If you want get item by label, you can implement your own `TreeDataProvider` with the method to return it.

Comment: Rus, thank you for your comment. I have seen this question, but the way to return the item is precisely what I am looking for... then yes, I will use reveal to select the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem correctly, you can do something like this:
(this code extends the example you mentioned)

```
class TreeDataProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<TreeItem> {
    // ...

    /** returns item object by its label */
    getTreeItemByLabel(label: string)
    {
        // more complicated logics should go here to find deep nested items
        return this.data.find(x => x.label == 'cars').children.find(x => x.label == label);
    }

    // this method from vscode.TreeDataProvider interface needed to enable reveal method.
    // logics should also be more complicated
    getParent(element: TreeItem): vscode.ProviderResult<TreeItem>
    {
        if (element.label == 'cars') return undefined;
        return this.data[0];
    }
}

// register provider and view
const provider = new TreeDataProvider();
const treeView = vscode.window.createTreeView("exampleView", { treeDataProvider: provider });

// get item by label and make it selected
const item = provider.getTreeItemByLabel("BMW");
treeView.reveal(item, { focus: true, select: true });
```